# black screen after grub-install --force

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a dual boot pc. In my Ubuntu partition I was stuck in grub rescue mode. Following some answers on here I was able to grub-update and grub-install my ubuntu partition.

My Ubuntu partition have an ext2 file system and I had the problem  `File system 'ext2' doesn't support embedding`, I "solved" it using `grub-install /dev/sda --force` and then I used `grub-update`.

My problem now is that when I select Ubuntu at start up I obtain a black screen with a white dash (as for typing but I cannot type anything). I cannot load GRUB menu. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why EXT2? What Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have Ubuntu 20.04, dual boot with Windows 10

Comment: So why EXT2, deprecated since 2009?

Comment: I actually have no idea… a friend of mine created the dual boot for me. It was working fine until 3 days ago. Then I had the problem of file system unknown grub rescue mode that I “solved” as explained above and now I cannot access Ubuntu at all

Comment: Clearly not a solution. Better to just reinstall Ubuntu properly which means with EXT4.